# RTI DDS Connector Compile Fails

Tags: c#, f#, msbuild, cakebuild, data-distribution-service

I am trying to compile C# Connector of RTI Connext DDS.

I clone the [C# Connector](https://github.com/rticommunity/rticonnextdds-connector-cs) from this address to my computer via git.

But when I go to the \rticonnextdds-connector-cs directory via powershell and run the "build.ps1" command, I get the following error:

```
Could not load C:\Users\eco_p\rticonnextdds-connector-cs\tools\Addins\altcover.api.5.0.663\lib\net45\BlackFox.CommandLine.dll (missing FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

Can someone who has gone through these stages before can help? How do I fix this error?

**UPDATE :**

To fix the error I installed Visual [F# Tools 4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48179) and the error disappeared but now I get an error like this:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /warnaserror
```

**EDIT for Reinier:** 
I am trying to integrate DDS into my project created with Unity3D. Unity3D works with Mono and RTI Connext for C# is based on CLI/C++ and it is not 100% compatible with Mono. 
It is necessary to use C # Connector for this. 
Other details about this issue are described [here](https://community.rti.com/forum-topic/support-unity-game-engine):

**EDIT for alexc:** 
Sorry for missing information I am using Visual Studio 2015 version.
And Build Engine version is : 14.0

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking for free help to solve *your* problem. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that using capital letters in the title was perceived as impolite. I just wanted to draw attention. I will take care not to do this after that.

Comment: Did you clone recursively like stated in the readme?

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/rticommunity/rticonnextdds-connector-cs --recursive`

Comment: yes, I cloned correctly, but still I get an error at compile stage.

Comment: Not answering your question, I do wonder what is your reason for using the C# Connector and not the "real" Connext C# API?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? What's the MSBuild version?

Comment: The post has been edited for questions.

Comment: From [this post](https://community.rti.com/forum-topic/c-connector-building-error), it looks like your issue was resolved. Would you mind updating your question here, or adding an answer to your own question, with the resolution?